# Plot a graph in matlab using a color for each vertex

Tags: matlab, graph

I need to plot the graph given three parameters:

Graph adjacency matrix X(n*n)
2D Coordinates matrix for each vertex V(n*2)
Matrix containing the color of each vertex using rgb composition (n*3)

Is there any tool I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Can you show a simple example of your matrix? You could try using     scatter3()

Comment: I don't believe scatter3() is meant to plot graphs, edges will not be represented.

Comment: give your `X`, `V` matrix

Comment: X=[             0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0    
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0    
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0    
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0    
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0    
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1    
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1    
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1    
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1    
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1    
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0    ]

Comment: V=[    841263,532831181 540650,817455598    
415425,013001886 909641,995354518    
-142304,838273285 989831,441880933     
-654850,733945285 755759,574354258       
-959482,973614497 281742,556841430        
-959482,973614498 -281722,556841429    
-654850,733945285 -755739,574354258    
-142304,838273285 -989811,441880933    
415425,013001886 -909621,995354519    
841263,532831181 -540630,817455598    
1000010 9,99999999886689    ]
V represents the coordinates of the edge of a polygon in this case.

Comment: Number of vertices is n=11.

Comment: Sorry<br>X=[<br>             0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0   <br> 
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0    <br>
0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0    <br>
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0    <br>
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0    <br>
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1    <br>
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1    <br>
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1    <br>
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1    <br>
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1    <br>
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0    ]<br>

Comment: do the same for `V` ?

Comment: V=[ 841263,532831181 540650,817455598 415425,013001886 --- 909641,995354518 -142304,838273285 989831,441880933 ---  654850,733945285 755759,574354258 -959482,973614497 ---  281742,556841430 -959482,973614498 -281722,556841429 --- 654850,733945285 -755739,574354258 -142304,838273285 --- 989811,441880933 415425,013001886 -909621,995354519 --- 841263,532831181 -540630,817455598 1000010 9,99999999886689 ] ---

Comment: `841263` a single number?

Comment: To make things simple I've changed the coordinates:
V= [
18 15 ;
14 19 ;
8 19 ;
3 17 ;
0 12 ;
0,4 7 ;
3,4 2,4 ;
8,5 0,1 ;
14 0,9 ;
18 4,59 ;
20 10 ;]

Comment: Try this: gplot(X,V). However this cannot allow you to pick a unique color for each location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you want

```
%// i took some random values as your input was not clear. 
%// you could replace it with your own values.

V = [ 18    15 ;  
      14    19 ;
       8    19 ;
       3    17 ;
       0    12 ;
       0     4 ;
       2     4 ; 
       8     5 ;
      14     9 ;
       4    20 ; 
      20    10]; 

C = rand(11,3);  %// replace it with your original color matrix
k = 1:11;
hold on
scatter(V(:,1), V(:,2), [],C,'filled');
gplot(X(k,k),V(k,:),'-');
text(V(:,1), V(:,2),[repmat('  ',11,1), num2str((1:11)')]);
hold off
```

Output:

[image]